# How to calculate the minimum maximum and average values for each column in a dataset using MapReduce in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, mapreduce

Assuming I have a large data set, here is an abbreviated part of it

```
Status,column1,column2,column3,column4
Healthy,4.5044,0.7443,6.34,1.9052
Patient,4.4284,0.9073,5.6433,1.6232
Patient,4.5291,1.0199,6.113,1.0565
Healthy,5.2258,0.6125,7.9504,0.1547
Healthy,4.8834,0.5786,5.6021,0.5942
Patient,5.7422,0.8862,5.1013,0.9402
Healthy,6.5076,0.5438,7.153,0.6711
```

I know the easiest way to do this is to use **df.describe().show()** in pyspark, but
How can I use Mapreduce in pyspark to calculate the minimum maximum and average of each column?

Comment: There are many ways to calculate its summary, but the hard requirement is to use MapReduce in pyspark, if someone can show the mapreduce operation, it would be appreciated and would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`df.describe()` uses native Spark function to run the computation.
You can explicitly use select expressions to get the results.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("Healthy", 4.5044, 0.7443, 6.34, 1.9052,),
        ("Patient", 4.4284, 0.9073, 5.6433, 1.6232,),
        ("Patient", 4.5291, 1.0199, 6.113, 1.0565,),
        ("Healthy", 5.2258, 0.6125, 7.9504, 0.1547,),
        ("Healthy", 4.8834, 0.5786, 5.6021, 0.5942,),
        ("Patient", 5.7422, 0.8862, 5.1013, 0.9402,),
        ("Healthy", 6.5076, 0.5438, 7.153, 0.6711,), ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Status", "column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", ))

select_expr = []

for c in df.columns:
    for metric in [F.min, F.max, F.avg]:
        select_expr.append(metric(c))

df.select(*select_expr).show()

"""
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+
|min(Status)|max(Status)|avg(Status)|min(column1)|max(column1)|     avg(column1)|min(column2)|max(column2)|      avg(column2)|min(column3)|max(column3)|     avg(column3)|min(column4)|max(column4)|      avg(column4)|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+
|    Healthy|    Patient|       null|      4.4284|      6.5076|5.117271428571429|      0.5438|      1.0199|0.7560857142857141|      5.1013|      7.9504|6.271871428571429|      0.1547|      1.9052|0.9921571428571428|
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

just group by column you want to find max,min and avg and use aggregate function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    
df.groupBy(df.Status)\
.agg(F.max(df.column1), F.min(df.column1), F.avg(df.column1)).show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you specify the output you want in your question or what you'll be using the output for, but the below should cover most use cases

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [("Healthy", 4.5044, 0.7443, 6.34, 1.9052,),
        ("Patient", 4.4284, 0.9073, 5.6433, 1.6232,),
        ("Patient", 4.5291, 1.0199, 6.113, 1.0565,),
        ("Healthy", 5.2258, 0.6125, 7.9504, 0.1547,),
        ("Healthy", 4.8834, 0.5786, 5.6021, 0.5942,),
        ("Patient", 5.7422, 0.8862, 5.1013, 0.9402,),
        ("Healthy", 6.5076, 0.5438, 7.153, 0.6711,), ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("Status", "column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", ))

columns = df.columns
columns.remove('Status')

cols_to_agg = [f(c) for c in columns for f in [F.min, F.max, F.avg]]

df.agg(*cols_to_agg)

+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+
|min(column1)|max(column1)|     avg(column1)|min(column2)|max(column2)|      avg(column2)|min(column3)|max(column3)|     avg(column3)|min(column4)|max(column4)|      avg(column4)|
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+
|      4.4284|      6.5076|5.117271428571429|      0.5438|      1.0199|0.7560857142857144|      5.1013|      7.9504|6.271871428571428|      0.1547|      1.9052|0.9921571428571428|
+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+
```

or as Igor mentioned you could do a groupby to get a more granular breakdown

```
df.groupBy('status').agg(*cols_to_agg)
```

or if you want both use a [rollup](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.rollup.html?highlight=rollup#pyspark-sql-dataframe-rollup) as this will give the result of both of the above in a single aggregation and output.

```
df.rollup('status').agg(*cols_to_agg+[F.grouping_id()]).show()
+-------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+-------------+
| status|min(column1)|max(column1)|      avg(column1)|min(column2)|max(column2)|      avg(column2)|min(column3)|max(column3)|     avg(column3)|min(column4)|max(column4)|      avg(column4)|grouping_id()|
+-------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+-------------+
|Patient|      4.4284|      5.7422|            4.8999|      0.8862|      1.0199|0.9378000000000001|      5.1013|       6.113|5.619199999999999|      0.9402|      1.6232|1.2066333333333332|            0|
|Healthy|      4.5044|      6.5076|5.2802999999999995|      0.5438|      0.7443|            0.6198|      5.6021|      7.9504|         6.761375|      0.1547|      1.9052|0.8312999999999999|            0|
|   null|      4.4284|      6.5076| 5.117271428571429|      0.5438|      1.0199|0.7560857142857144|      5.1013|      7.9504|6.271871428571428|      0.1547|      1.9052|0.9921571428571428|            1|
+-------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------+------------------+------------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+------------------+-------------+
```

Note that `df.agg` is just an alias for `df.groupBy().agg()` and [grouping_id](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.grouping_id.html?highlight=grouping_id#pyspark-sql-functions-grouping-id) is the null safe way to indicate which aggregation level a row belongs to

lastly you could consider putting the outputs in a more friendly format like a map column, which outputs the below

```py
cols_to_agg = [F.create_map(f.__name__, f(c)) for f in [F.min, F.max, F.avg] for c in columns]
df.agg(*cols_to_agg)


+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|column1                                                 |column2                                                  |column3                                                 |column4                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|{min -> 4.4284, max -> 6.5076, avg -> 5.117271428571429}|{min -> 0.5438, max -> 1.0199, avg -> 0.7560857142857144}|{min -> 5.1013, max -> 7.9504, avg -> 6.271871428571428}|{min -> 0.1547, max -> 1.9052, avg -> 0.9921571428571428}|
+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

which can then be collected to a python dictionary

```py
df.agg(*cols_to_agg).collect()[0].asDict()


{'column1': {'avg': 5.117271428571429, 'max': 6.5076, 'min': 4.4284},
 'column2': {'avg': 0.7560857142857144, 'max': 1.0199, 'min': 0.5438},
 'column3': {'avg': 6.271871428571428, 'max': 7.9504, 'min': 5.1013},
 'column4': {'avg': 0.9921571428571428, 'max': 1.9052, 'min': 0.1547}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it does solve the required output perfectly, but the annoying thing is that the requirement is to use MapReduce in pyspark to do it. Are you familiar with MapReduce, please? If not, I'd still appreciate it

Comment: Why do you need to use MapReduce if you have Spark? you can do MapReduce type of transformations with the RDD API but it isn't strictly the same as pure MapReduce. Most likely you could get a better answer by giving a bit more context and explaining as to why you need to do this in MapReduce